# What must be $ k + m$ if the following linear system is consistent?

Tags: matrices

$x+3y-z = 51 $

$2x+4y+z= k   $

$2y-3z= m$

I just started learning linear systems and I am clueless about how to proceed after obtaining row echelon form of the matrix. Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Note: **If a linear system is consistent, it has at least one solution.**

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: How to show a system of linear equations is consistent?

Comment: If you obtained the rref, you should display it -MathJax tip - write `$\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}$` etc. to render matrices. Knowing the rref should be enough for you to check consistency

Comment: @annabella what is the definition of a system of linear equations being consistent?

Comment: There must be a typo since with the given coefficients, the system is consistent for all $k$ and $m$ and always has a unique solution.

Comment: @Peter yes I've just corrected it sorry.

Comment: @user_194421 It means the system has at least one solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning the matrix into row echelon form; if you did it correctly the answer should look something like this (but not necessarily the same as mine)
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 3 & -1 \\
2 & 4 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & -3 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
51 \\
k \\
m \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 3 & -1 \\
0 & -2 & 3 \\
0 & 2 & -3 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
51 \\
k-102 \\
m \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 3 & -1 \\
0 & -2 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
51 \\
k-102 \\
m+k-102 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 3 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -3/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
51 \\
-k/2+51 \\
m+k-102 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
Reduced row echelon form (should be unique)
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 7/2 \\
0 & 1 & -3/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{matrix}\right]
=
\left[\begin{matrix}
3k/2-51/2 \\
-k/2+51 \\
m+k-102 \\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
Of course, the equation is consistent only if
$$m+k-102=0$$
$$m+k=102\text.$$
If that is fulfilled, then it has infinitely many solutions of the form $$x=-\frac72z+\frac32k-\frac{51}2$$
$$y=\frac32z-\frac12k+51$$
$$z=z\text.$$

In conclusion, in order that the system of equations be consistent, then $m+k$ must equal $102$. There are infinitely many combinations of $m$ and $k$ which fulfill that.

Comment: thank you so much!